# Decrease Bootstrap input field width

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap input field that I need to decrease the width.

My Code

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" />
```

Here I try to reduce the width using `sm-input`, but nothing happens.

```
<input type="text" class="input-qty form-control input-sm" />
```

This is my complete code:

```
var row = $('<tr><td></td><td>' + $(this).text() + '</td><td>' + $(this).attr('RetailPrice') + '</td><td>' + '<input type="text" class="input-qty form-control col-md-2" data-id="' + $(this).val() + '" data-prod-id="' + $(this).attr('Value') + '">' + '</td><td>' + '<input type="text" class="ddd form-control">' + '</td><td class="tot">0</td><td><img id="imgdel" src="../../Images/delete.png" alt="" onclick="deleteclick(this)" title="Delete" /></td><td>' + $(this).attr('Value') + '</td></tr>');
table.append(row);
```

Comment: Have you tried an inline style or a page scoped style with !important?

Comment: if you read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-control-sizes), `input-sm` makes the height smaller

Comment: @RobEpstein I didn't do any inline styling just use bootstrap css features. that input-qty for the another calculation purpose

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Bootstrap 3 Give it a "col-md-" class for example:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-4" />
```

Or if this is still to large:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control col-md-2" />
```

You should take a look at the [Bootstarp documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) regarding the grid system.

Usage:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I use that but nothing happen

Comment: please post a little more of your code. I can also give you a brief example of the usage of the grid. I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In `form-control` it takes `100% width`

Using `row & columns` logic only we can conrtol the width like this:

```
<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
                 <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            </div>
        </div>
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/7649/)

Comment: pls check my original post.here i can't use <div>

Comment: already its working fine na. Then what kind of solution you looking for?

Comment: I need to decrese the size of that text boxes

Comment: set padding to that particular `<td>` like `<td style='padding:0px 15px 0px 15px'>`

Answer (score 0):

wrap form-controls in a form group:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-4 col-sm-4">
    <input type="text" class="input-qty form-control" />
</div>
```

Comment: pls check my original post.